# Exponential families as families of limite distributions of Markov processes

Tags: markov-process, exponential-family, maximum-entropy

An exponential family verifies a maximum entropy property: each density is the maximum entropy density given the expectation of its sufficient statistic.

On the other hand, from my understanding, the entropy of the distribution at time t of a Markov process increases with t.

Given an exponential family, is there a standard way to build a family of Markov processes whose distributions converge to those of the exponential family?

Thank you